# knockout foreach binding only showing first item repeatedly

Tags: knockout.js

Getting issue in binding the ko observableArray to table.
[jsFiddle][1].

http://jsfiddle.net/chetanpawar0989/do6o7wtb/

`<tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.TakenCourses">
            <tr>
                <td> <span data-bind="text: courseName"></span></td>
                <td> <span data-bind="text: courseCredits"></span></td>
                <td> <button data-bind="click: removeCourse">Remove</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>`

On jsFiddle it's just showing first item. However when I add the course, the length of array is increasing and the latest courses are getting added to takenCourses array (can be seen in alert box) That means I am goofing up something in binding the data.

Also when i run the same code in my webpage, it shows the first course repeatedly when I add the course.

The remove functionality is not working too.

I am new to KO and learning the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no function `removeCourse` in the `course` objects.

```
<button data-bind="click: removeCourse">Remove</button>
```

should therefore be

```
<button data-bind="click: $root.removeCourse">Remove</button>
```

---

You might though want to redesign everything slightly, maybe like this:

```
var course = function(name, credits, selected) {
    var self = this;

    this.courseName = name;
    this.courseCredits = credits;
    this.selected = ko.observable(!!selected);

    this.unselectCourse = function() {
        self.selected(false);
    };
};
```

Instead of maintaining lists of selected and unselected courses, I would advise to make this a property of each course. In the view model, you would then use dynamic lists:

```
function NCSUCourseModel() 
{
    var self = this;

    //Static list of available courses
    self.courses = ko.observableArray([
        new course("Orientation", 1, true),
        new course("Operating Sytems", 3),
        new course("Algorithms", 3),
        // ...
    ]);

    self.selectedCourse = ko.observable();

    self.AvailableCourses = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.courses(), function(item) {
            return item.selected() == false;
        });
    });

    self.TakenCourses = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.courses(), function(item) {
            return item.selected() == true;
        });
    });

    self.AddCourse = function() {
        this.selectedCourse().selected(true);
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/do6o7wtb/2/

Comment: Thanks Niko. New approach is good but just wanted to know what was the problem with the old one. I tried making `<button data-bind="click: $root.removeCourse">Remove</button>` as per your previous comment but still it didn't work.

Comment: Your original JSFiddle mixes the use of `this` and `self`.  The value of `this` inside the `removeCourse` function will NOT refer to the instance of the NCSUCourseModel instance but knockout will rescope to the Course instance.

Comment: You should use `$parent`, not `$root`, in a foreach binding to refer to the instance of the viewmodel containing the array.  In anything other than a simplistic viewModel will `$root` be the correct instance.